# Max value function for an array

Tags: c#

I have read in a file, sorted the file by into three columns and put all of the data in each columns into 3 arrays. I now need to make a method to get the max value out of the second column array. This is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    string file1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\file1.txt");

    List<double> Array1 = new List<double>();
    List<double> Array2 = new List<double>();
    List<double> Array3 = new List<double>();

    IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(@"C:\File1.txt");

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string[] columns = line.Split(',');

        if (columns.Length != 3)
        {
            continue; // skips this line
        }

        Array1.Add(Convert.ToDouble(columns[0]));
        Array2.Add(Convert.ToDouble(columns[1]));
        Array3.Add(Convert.ToDouble(columns[2]));
    }

Console.WriteLine(Max(Array1.ToArray()));
}
static double Max (double[] x)
{
    double maxValue = x.Max();
    return maxValue;
}
```

ERROR: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected.

I need to fix the Max Method and also I do not know how to Say that it is Array 2 that we need to get the max value of. I then need to go back up to the main and Use the Max Method to get the maximum value of array 2. Clearly their are beginners errors in the Max function but I have researched the problem andI am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: I feel this code is not yours. please read some tutorial about c# first before stepping into much advanced programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
static double Max (double[] x)
{
    double[] x // This line shouldn't be here

    double maxValue = x.Max();
    return maxValue;
}
```

You're declaring `double[] x` twice, in the parameter as well as in the method. This will mess things up.

Also, try not to have the same name for your method as the one from the API, just to make code easier to read.

Lastly, you never called the method from main. :P

Comment: Thank you this works. Also in the main I wrote:'Max(Array1) and console.writeline(Max(array1));' what is wrong here?

Comment: Nice to hear ;D - Could you show the stack trace or tell me what is/isn't happening?

Comment: `console.writeline` is wrong. coding is case sensitive. do this `Console.Writeline(Max(array1));`

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Max(Array1));` that is

Comment: In main if I called the function and inside it put Array1 I thought this would get the max value of the array but it returns an error: Max(Array1);

Comment: Sorry you are correct. My error was caused because I have not closed the file at the end. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: oops. you need to convert this to array. `Console.Writeline(Max(array1.ToArray()));` @NoviceCoder11

Comment: But also I need to close the file at the end of my code. I have tried to use .Close(); but it has not been successful. Once I do this my code is complete! Do you know how?

Comment: Could you update the question with the code you have currently?

Comment: Ok I just updated it there.  See the end of the code where it says the exact error I have.

Comment: You put `Console.WriteLine(Max(Array1.ToArray()));` outside of the main method

Comment: Apologies I typed the code incorrectly. It is inside the main method. But the problem now lies in Closing the file I have imported. The error is ' Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected.'

Comment: Just confirming, you are getting this error still after moving the function call to main? `Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected.` is the error you would get if you tried to call a method outside of a method.

Comment: Hold on I will close and open the file just to refresh it.

Comment: Oh you are correct. Thanks you so so much it is now working!!

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace Your_Name_Space
{
    class Your_Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"D:\file1.txt");

            List<double> Array1 = new List<double>();
            List<double> Array2 = new List<double>();
            List<double> Array3 = new List<double>();

            IEnumerable<string> lines = File.ReadLines(@"D:\File1.txt");

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string[] columns = line.Split(',');

                if (columns.Length != 3)
                {
                    continue; // skips this line
                }

                Array1.Add(Convert.ToDouble(columns[0]));
                Array2.Add(Convert.ToDouble(columns[1]));
                Array3.Add(Convert.ToDouble(columns[2]));
            }

            Console.WriteLine(Max(Array1.ToArray()));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static double Max(double[] x)
        {
            double maxValue = x.Max();
            return maxValue;
        }
    }
}
```

file1.text's content is like below :

```
1, 2, 3 
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

All your codes ran. When the above code is compiled and executed, it produces the following result:

```
7
```

'end-of-file expected' error's reason is braces excess. You should control your braces. And value 7 isn't second coloumn.